# Accessing referenced dll in WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF singleton service

```
  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
 public class MyService: IMyService
  {
        ...my service code...
  }
```

I am referencing a Dll in this service and using some of its methods.It compiles fine.But when I host my service on IIS it gives error that assembly is not found.Can anybody point out what is missing here.

The 3rd party dll is 64 bit .Net dll and my system,IIS and service are also 64 bit.
I even checked IIS property to launch 32 bit worker thread,thats also false.

The dll has all static methods

Is it IIS problem or my implementation?

Comment: You can diagnose with the [fusion log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you copied that DLL on IIS when you have published App ? Have you marked copy output true on referenced DLL ?
Thanks